# Remove the leading zero from date

Tags: datetime2

I like to print dates formatted in this way: `6 October 2018`.  Usually, I just type the date by hand.  But I tried to set things up so that `\today` would format dates the way I like.  I must have only tested it when the day number was two digits.  I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{datetime2}
\DTMnewdatestyle{strunkdate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{##3 \DTMenglishmonthname{##2} ##1}
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DTMsetdatestyle{strunkdate}}% after babel loaded, or babel stomps on this
\begin{document}
Today is \today.
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this prints `06 October 2018`, with a leading zero to force a two-digit day.  How do I get `6 October 2018`, without the leading zero?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package may have a specific command, but you can use the TeX `\number` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{datetime2}
\DTMnewdatestyle{strunkdate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\number##3\ \DTMenglishmonthname{##2} ##1}
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DTMsetdatestyle{strunkdate}}% after babel loaded, or babel stomps on this
\begin{document}
Today is \today.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's actually the method recommended by the manual of `datetime2`, page 95. No caveat about the problem of following space, unfortunately.

Comment: @egreg didn't occur to me to look in a manual!

Comment: In order to preserve full expandability to character tokens, `\number\numexpr##3\relax\space\DTMenglishmonthname{##2} ##1` could be better.

Comment: @egreg I did wonder about that but expansion unlikely to be needed here I would guess and `\ `  looks nicer in the code and doesn't require an essay on what it does:-)

Comment: Works great! Is the expandability that you're worried about, @egreg, that of the characters in the day number itself?

Comment: @dedded If you want to use the date for other purposes, splitting it in parts, for instance, having control sequences in the middle can be of a hindrance. But probably it's not the case with your application.

Comment: Nothing like that.  I can imagine passing it whole to another command.